# Where is the documentation of Xposed API

Tags: xposed

There are only tutorials available.
https://github.com/rovo89/XposedBridge/wiki

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you are:
[Javadoc reference of the Xposed Framework API](http://api.xposed.info/reference/packages.html)